# how to create such a php script so that it can take same argument from other php script and command line both

Tags: php, command-line, scripting

I am creating PHP script which is taking arguments from command line right now but after sometime it may change to simply including my PHP script.

How can I prepare my script for both scenarios?

Can I create such PHP script so that it can take argument from command line and from other script which is simply including my script?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the idea of "taking arguments from another php script". Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

let's say script A is the first script that can be called from the commnad line and included in another script and script B is the one that includes it.
if you include script A in B you'll have access to any variable in script B. so why don't you add a check in script A to see if a param has been passed from the command line, if no params have been passed from the command line use whatever variables you created in script B

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you'll be forced to use a parameter to tell if your script is using the commandline parameter, or if he will call your other script.

In your script, you can do something like :

```
if (!strcmp($argv[1], "-s"))
    shell_exec('php YourOtherScript.php [put_args_here]');
else
    your_current_script($argv);
```

Then, if you want to execute your other script, you'll make a command like :

```
php MyScript.php -s [args]
```

Otherwise, simply put the standard arguments :

```
php MyScript.php [args]
```

Answer (score 0):

could be as simple as:

```
if(isset($argv[1])){ 
//commadn line arguments
$foo=$argv[1]
}else{
//not
$foo=$foo
}
```